# Can I have both Maven and Gradle installed on my machine

Tags: java, maven, gradle

Just wanted to know, can I have both Maven and Gradle on my machine. I'm getting myself familiar with both the tools, I have already installed Gradle on my machine, now want to check out maven as well. Is it safe to have both on a single machine. I think both use .m2 as their local repository directory. I'm doing this for learning purposes.

Comment: Yes, you can, of course. Why couldn't you? And why don't you just try? BTW, no, Gradle doesn't use .m2 (except if you choose to publish your own artefacts in your local maven repo).

Comment: I'm doing this on my office dev machine which already uses Gradle, just wanted to be sure so I don't screw things up.

Comment: Better safe than sorry? I like you. For the future - try setting up small VMs and trying on them. If you screw up, you can just remove the VM or roll back to VM image that you've created before trying it out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can!

This is two diffrenet programs that not affect each other. It's like to install java , C# and python on the same machine, there is nothing wrong with this.

Note: if you want you can change the default local repostiory path (e.g .m2)
that maven use from the `settings.xml` file

Hope it was helpful